# Not able to display the Content of Table

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

models.py has

```
class Question(models.Model):
    Question_Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Question_Text = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Question_Text

    def __int__(self):
        return self.Question_Id

class QuestionChoices(models.Model):
    Choice_Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Question_Choices_Question_Id = models.ForeignKey("Question", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Choice = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    Is_Right_Choice = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py file has the below

```
def QuestionDisplay(request):
    retrieved_questions_id = Question.objects.values("Question_Id")
    retrieved_questions = Question.objects.filter(Question_Id = retrieved_questions_id)
    display_content = {retrieved_questions_id: retrieved_questions}
    return render(request, 'cgkapp/Question_page.html', context=display_content)
```

templates folder Question_page.html has

```
{% block body_block %}
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Questions</th>
        </thead>
        {% for quest in display_content %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{quest.Question_Text}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

The page displays the Questions as the Table header but not the actual questions from the models. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a **typo**, you have missed **}** after `Question_Text}`

```
<td>{{quest.Question_Text}}</td>
```

> Update After Comment

Do like below, don't know why but you are getting very much confused I think. It will solve your problem

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    # `id` primary key is already present no need to define.
    question_text = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

**views.py**

```
def question_display(request):
    # There is no need of 2 queries, you can get that in single query.
    questions = Question.objects.all();

    # If you want only question ids 
    question_ids = Question.objects.values('id')

    # You can send multiple variables to the template using context dictionary and directly access them there.
    context = {'questions': questions, 'question_ids':question_ids}

    return render(request, 'cgkapp/Question_page.html', context)
```

**In template**

```
 #Show questions with only question texts
 <table>
    <thead>
        <th>Questions</th>
    </thead>
    {% for quest in questions %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{quest.question_text}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

# If you also want to show question text with ids.
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Question ID</th>
        <th>Question Text</th>
    </thead>
    {% for quest in questions %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{quest.id}}</td>
            <td>{{quest.question_text}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
# If you want to show only Question IDs
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Question ID</th>
    </thead>
    {% for quest in question_ids %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{quest}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

#This same thing can be done this way also.
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Question ID</th>
    </thead>
    {% for quest in questions %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{quest.id}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: oh.. Thanks.. but after correcting that also the records are not displaying..is there any problem with the way the views.py is written?

Comment: Did this help you in understanding the flow?

Comment: Thanks Astik.. I got the flow now.. basically I want ed to display the questions from question table and related choices for the questions from questionchoices table.. I will try that next...

Answer (score 0):

If it was just the typo, you'll see the string `{{quest.Question_Text}` being rendered. The problem is with your context. You're sending a dictionary there where keys are supposed to be strings,

`display_content = {'retrieved_questions_id': retrieved_questions}`

And then, in your template, you would iterate over `retrieved_questions_id` and not `display_content`. `display_content` is just the name of the dictionary where you're storing the values.

Comment: but if I change the display_content to {% for quest in retrieved_questions_id %} in the template it is giving error  for " return render(request, 'cgkapp/Question_page.html', context=display_content) " as below
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/questions/
Django Version: 2.0.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

Comment: That is because your system is now working. Now, fix your queries, They're wrong. `retrieved_questions_id` is a queryset. You cannot pass it to a param in filter. `Question_Id` in `Question.objects.filter(Question_Id = retrieved_questions_id)` should be one question id not a queryset.

Comment: ah.. I understood now I passed the queryset instead of individual value.. but now how I can re-write this to get the question_id and Question as the dictionay output? Any help in this regard?

Comment: Would be good to ask it in another question since this has a different context and would become confusing.